# IBM AIX: How do I set up SSH X forwarding on an unprivileged user with no home?

Tags: ssh, x11, aix, ssh-tunneling

Long story short: I have an AIX server where my user is unprivileged and has no home directory, and it is not easy to fix this because OS-level management of this server is outside of my jurisdiction.

I need to be able to do X over SSH on that server in order to run an app's configuration, which is graphical only. I can't set my `XAUTHORITY` variable on my login profile because I don't have a profile and I'm not sure if I'm allowed to configure one. What can I do?

Comment: You don't normally need to set `XAUTHORITY`. Does the server authorize X11 forwarding? What does `ssh -X aixserver.example.com export` show?